# I cannot import my conatcts from outlook to my nokia lumia phobne 630

Tags: insider-preview, outlook

I have a contacts in outlook but i cannot import from outlook to my nokia lumia 630 phone.Please any one suggest me how to import contacts from outlook.

Comment: By Outlook do you mean the Outlook desktop program or the Outlook.com webmail service? How are you trying to import the contacts? Are you getting any error messages? Please provide any and all relevant details to make it easier to help you.

Comment: outlook.com webmail service

Comment: Contacts from Outlook.com should be imported automatically when you sign in with your Microsoft account (which I assume you've done). Is that not working?

Comment: No that is not working!!

Comment: Please clarify in what way it's not working. Do you get an error message? Can you sync your Outlook.com email and calendar events? Can you access your OneDrive or the Store, for example?

Comment: yes I can synchronize and access Onedrive and store but I could not get the contacts and no error message is occuring